# When to use thread efficiently

Tags: java, multithreading

This question comes out of my practical inexperience with this issue. I'm not going to lie, it's a newbie yet essential question that I've always been somewhat reluctant to asking. Before pushing this as subjective, I kindly ask to read the whole post.

I've read quite a bit into `threads` particularly in `Java` however have never actually used them myself. I know it's imperative to use them to maximise the efficiency of your application, however I've never quite known *when* or to a certain extent how.

So I decided to create a Math Quiz application, including the GUI, highscore system etc. - within the main menu the I have my menu bar with a checkbox menu items toggling whether or not the user wishes to use the application with a particular theme or not.

[image]

Obviously I want this option to continuously be checked during the lifetime of it's frame. Putting all these factors together made me wonder whether or not I should create a thread within the frame class to continuously check without affecting anything outside it.

---

So here's my question(s). Is this an ideal scenario to opt to use threads? If yes, what issues may arise using them?

If no, may I ask why not and where I could possibly use them within my desired application.

---

I'd also like to specify that yes, I've read quite a large number of articles and small books regarding threads. However being self-taught in the subject the only way I properly learn is by doing. Hope you understand.

Comment: If you're using those settings only when choosing which question to show to a user, then you don't need another thread. Avoid the complexity and just check as part of the get-a-new-question method.

Comment: @PaulHicks = However the questions show up on another frames aswell, I would like the theme to be used on those frames, not only this one.

Comment: @Juxhin _Obviously I want this option to continuously be checked during the lifetime of it's frame_ No, you probably don't want to do that. Instead you want to fire an event when the user changes the option. This is not a good use of a thread in my opinion. I can't really see any use of threads in this application, except maybe calculate highscores or something in the background. Not all applications benefit from the kind of parallelism threads introduce.

Comment: @jpw - Thanks for the comment, it's good to get someone else's opinion on it. From what it seems I should stick to your option which is what I normally do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on the ui framework you are using to create the GUI, there is already some kind of a thread, that processes all the user actions, renders the controls etc. So, the usual way to do what you want here is to implement a callback action on the button, that will be invoked when the user clicks on it, not to check the button state periodically in a thread.

A better case for using threads, might be, for instance, something like parallel calculations. For example, imagine, that you want the count the total number of words in 10 (or, perhaps, 1000?) large files. One way to do that, would be to open those files one by one, read, and count. Alternatively, you could implement a generic job, that knows how to count words in a single file. Then, create a pool of threads (you don't want 10000 threads going at the same time, a fixed size pool would be a better idea), and a queue of files that need to be processed. Each thread in the pool picks the next item from the queue, counts the words in the given file, places the number on the output queue, and proceeds to the next input item, unless the queue is empty.

The main thread would then put all the filenames on the input queue, and poll the output queue for the numbers, and sum them all together. Ones all threads finish, and the output queue is empty, you'll have your final count.

This would be faster, than reading files one by one, especially, if you have multiple CPU cores available to your program (but still so even if you don't, because your reading can happen in parallel).

Does it make sense?

Comment: Quite the answer I was looking for. Thanks alot @Dima

Comment: How does the reading happen in parallel?  A regular hard disk won't give you better performance with that.  On the contrary, if the task is mostly I/O bound (because counting words is a really simple task, once the file is read) multi-threading won't do much for you.  On the other hand, if one thread can read while another can utilize the CPU doing some expensive computation that does not involve I/O, you can make more efficient use of your hardware.

Comment: I meant reading can be done in parallel with calculations. Word counting isn't rocket science, but not free computationally either. Processing files in parallel with reading may speed things up significantly. Also, remember, this is just an example. You could be analyzing SETI data instead of counting words. Finally, files do not have to be located on the same disk or even on the same computer. They don't even need to be files.